# App for viewing photos with properties (exif) display?

Tags: software-recommendation, photo-management

I'm looking for an app to view photos in folders, which can display properties (like time taken) next to photo. I want to view photos in folders as they are, without importing them to some library like in Shotwell or Digikam.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

## [gthumb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gthumb) [image: Install gthumb]

It is a powerful image viewer with many awesome features. I'm not sure if it can show the data next to the images, but you don't need to add a library.

If you enable the side pane in `eog` (View menu - you can get this info at the side as well.

[image]

To enable this btw you need to have the exif display plugin enabled in preferences. If you do not have this plugin, install [eog-plugins](http://packages.ubuntu.com/eog-plugins) [image: Install eog-plugins].

Comment: I have this option in EOG, in menu under "View", but it is disabled :/

Comment: @amoris: I updated my answer

Answer (score 15):

The default photo viewer (eog) will show metadata. If you open your photo, right click and select **Properties**. It will open a window that lists the metadata. You can then switch between photos and keep the metadata open beside it.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That's cool feature! I didn't know about it.

Comment: Great. What I'd love is a plugin to open those co-ordinates in another utility (Google Maps/Earth or OSM). Just copying the Lat/Long together to the clipboard would be a great compromise, it may be possible to script that.

Comment: This (`eog`) is also the default image viewer in Lubuntu. It can display some, but not all, metadata in a side panel, not needing a second window. Choose "View → Side Pane" or, in fullscreen mode, press `Ctrl + F9` to see it.

Comment: This is a nice feature. One thing that doesn't work well, though, is that "Image Properties > Details > Image Taking Conditions" closes down to Details overview, when moving on to the next photo. The properties dialog stays open but one has to click on the desired Details again.

Answer (score 1):

The Nautilus properties option is the quickest way and gives most important data, but it doesn't show things like GPS  coordinates if your images have geotagging.

For geolocation info you could try the lightweight **Gwenview** photo app found in the Ubuntu Software Center.

I also like the pre-installed Shotwell which also shows GPS data.

Answer (score 0):

While Digikam needs a database, it comes bundled with showPhoto (I have v 4.0.0beta3 right now, don't know if showPhoto was available in earlier Versions).
showPhoto is a standalone image viewer, without database. It displays pretty much the same metadata as Digikam does.
This is a good option for someone who needs both: indepth asset management and a quick viewer with editing features...

Personally I can recommend Gwenview, too. Metadata display can be fully customized and it displays every kind of data.